# How can I test this?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have this class:

```
public class EmployeeHours {

    public static final Integer STEP = 60;

    //more fields
    private Integer minutes;

    public void increaseMinutes(){//increase minutes by STEP}

    public void decreaseMinutes(){//decrease minutes by STEP, 0 whether negative}

}
```

And I want to test it:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldBeZeroSinceMinutesCantBeNegative() {
        int initialMinutes = 10;
        EmployeeHours employeeHours = new EmployeeHours(null, 1, initialMinutes);
        employeeHours.decreaseMinutes();
        assertThat(employeeHours.getMinutes(), is(0));
    }
```

This test is passing, beacuse I know that `STEP` is greater than 10. But if I change `STEP` to be 5, for instance, it won't pass.

Should I control this situations in the test itself? I mean:

```
if (STEP > initialMinutes) 
then expectSomething
else expectAnotherThing
```

Is it a good practice? How can I improve my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should improve your test to be as generic as possible.

Since `STEP` is a public field, you could initialize your `initialMinutes` variable to something like `STEP - 1`. This will correctly test the case where decreasing the minutes ends up in a negative value and it should be set to 0.

```
@Test
public void shouldBeZeroSinceMinutesCantBeNegative() {
    int initialMinutes = EmployeeHours.STEP - 1;
    EmployeeHours employeeHours = new EmployeeHours(null, 1, initialMinutes);
    employeeHours.decreaseMinutes();
    assertThat(employeeHours.getMinutes(), is(0));
}
```

Comment: +1 I think that's a good approach. When creating tests I would say it's not so much a good idea to add conditionals, otherwise you might end up adding complexity to it. I usually strive for simple tests, no conditionals, and in situations such as in this question I try to make variables / test method name express what I'm trying to convey.